# Row selection in a table through mouse move event using RxJs in Angular 2 app

Tags: typescript, angular, mouseevent, rxjs

I have an example of **Angular 2** application https://plnkr.co/edit/HdQnWqbg9HloWb4eYGHz with selection of table rows.

Row selection is done using a set of mouse event handlers  (`mousedown`, `mousemove`, `mouseup`).

Here is the template `table.comp.html`:

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let td of data; let i = index" 
        (mousedown)="onSelectionStart(i)" 
        (mousemove)="onSelection(i)" 
        (mouseup)="onSelectionEnd()" 
        [class.selected]="td">
      <td>row {{ i }}</td>
      <td>selected: {{ td }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Code of the `Component` (`table.comp.ts`) with event handlers:

```js
export class TableComponent {
    private data: Array<any> = [];
    constructor() {
        [1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(x => this.data.push(false))
    }
    mouseDown: boolean = false;
    select: boolean = false; // keep track of what we are currently doing: selecting or deselecting

    onSelectionStart(index) {
      this.mouseDown = true;
      this.select = !this.data[index];
    }
    onSelection(index) {
      if (!this.mouseDown)
          return;

      this.data[index] = this.select;
      console.log("You see me many times!");
    }
    onSelectionEnd() {
        this.mouseDown = false;
    }
}
```

I'd like to:

1. Avoid triggering re-selection of the same item multiple times. Message `"You see me many times!"` should appear only once per row.
2. Use **RxJs** to accomplish 1

Note: I'm on **Angular 2 RC3** and **RxJs 5**

Answer (score 2):

Use `mouseenter` instead of `mousemove`. This only gets called once, when the mouse enters the element.

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let td of data; let i = index" 
        (mousedown)="onSelectionStart(i)" 
        (mouseenter)="onSelection(i)" 
        (mouseup)="onSelectionEnd()" 
        [class.selected]="td">
      <td>row {{ i }}</td>
      <td>selected: {{ td }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

> See your updated [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HnDXIdCJ5PKYsTQuqEuV?p=preview) for a working example

Comment: It partially works. However, I need to keep track of `selection` status on `mousedown` as well, since it misses the first row (where I started selecting). And also `deselection` behaves oddly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's not possible declarative right now with Angular2 / Rxjs since you don't have an asynchronous data flow.

The following issue aims to provide observables from elements / events:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4062

You could achieve this by leveraging the `Observable.fromEvent` method directly...

Here is a sample:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <tr #tr ngFor="...">
    </tr>
  `
})
export class TableComponent {
  @ViewChildren('tr')
  trs:QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.trs.toArray().forEach((tr)=> {
      Observable.fromEvent(tr, 'mousedown').subscribe(event => {
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe, you mean https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromevent.md. I'm a bit confused, where should I use `Observable.fromEvent` and how to bind it to element/event.

Comment: Updated according to your answer: https://plnkr.co/edit/XLsAvcUJcueS723xJLZF. I don't get my console message inside `subscribe`